# Trouble changing font size - using documentclass article

Tags: fontsize, document-classes

Writing a paper, trouble with fonts. The font seems small to me - so I have tried a) changing it from 10 to 12 or 14 (see below), and b) trying to use extra larger font size (also below). I'm focusing on changing font prior to starting document.

But neither of these has successfully visibly changed the size of my font - it's as if nothing happened when I recompile.

I know often people recommend using other document classes. I'd prefer to stick to article, just bc I'm on a time crunch and changing classes wrecks this - but I'll take other suggestions if there's absolutely no other way. But...I hope this isn't the case!

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Article
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
%\documentclass[fontsize=48pt]{memoir}
%usepackage{anyfontsize}

\usepackage{lmodern}


%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{comment}

\title{Research proposal: Do early gender stereotypes development influence preferences over math education?
}
\author{Andrea Cornejo}


\begin{document}

\section{Motivation and Policy Background}
\
The origin and  development of gender stereotypes with respect to mathematics and science are issues that have not yet been resolved (Ellison and Swanson, 2010, Cheryan, 2012).

\end{document}
```

Comment: the document as posted has errors as it has two `\documentclass` commands, if I comment out `\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}` it uses 10pt fonts as expected (although it has several other issues and generates many warnings), if you add `[12pt]` then it will default to 12pt insetad of 10pt.

Comment: unrelated, best to use the default `utf8` encoding unless you have a particular need for `utf8x`,  there is no `letter` option,  the `todonotes `package warns about the margin settings and   there is a spurious `\ ` after the `\section{..}`.

Comment: You appear to have potentially conflicting duplicates so geometry is setting a4 which preferably could be done globally in the first line \documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{extarticle} so remove that second line as david suggested 20pt is as big as it gets and 12pt should be suitable, since from the extarticle readme "you will get warnings about overfull hboxes.  
If this is distracting you may put \sloppy in the preamble of your
document, but it is better to try to help Tex to find good line breaks
by inserting \- or rewriting short sections."

Comment: Oh! I see, alright I got it, I didn't realize my doc classes were conflicting. Thanks all!